# Add a new line after a String "},"

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a string i.e

`String x = "{Hi This Is My String}, I Want To Add New Line Here";`

I want to add a new line after "},"

output:

`{Hi This Is My String},`

`I Want To Add New Line Here`

I tried different methods but can not be able to add a new line afterwards
i tried:

`data=data.replaceFirst("\\},\\s?","\\[\n");`

it did not work. any suggestions?

Comment: how do you show your output? by a System.out.print()? define "did not work"

Comment: i have done that using `data = data.replace("},","},\n");`

Comment: @IqraButt Do you want to concat new line?

Comment: @IqraButt you have done 'what' exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Try this ...

```
String data = "{Hi This Is My String}, I Want To Add New Line Here";
 data=data.replaceAll("\\},","\\},\n");
```

Output will be :

{Hi This Is My String},
I Want To Add New Line Here

Answer (score 0):

If it is important that there is an opening bracket you might consider using a [lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html). 
The RegEx to select the position would be something like this:

```
        String s = "{Hi This Is My String}, I Want To Add New Line Here";
        String replace = s.replaceAll("(?<=\\{.*)\\},", "\\},\n");
        System.out.println(replace);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the match a bit more precise matching from an opening curly brace till a closing curly brace followed by a comma

```
{.*?},
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ftG9Eo/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/47eVpn)

In the replacement use the full match followed by a newline

```
$0\n
```

Example

```
String regex = "\\{[^\\{}]*\\},";
String x = "{Hi This Is My String}, I Want To Add New Line Here";
System.out.println(x.replaceAll(regex,"$0\n"));
```

Output

```
{Hi This Is My String},
 I Want To Add New Line Here
```

---

If you want to remove possible leading spaces, you could match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars `\h*` and capture the part with the curly's in group 1. Then use group 1 in the replacement.

```
({.*?},)\h*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KhlwAH/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/wrMmXu)

Example

```
String regex = "(\\{.*?\\},)\\h*";
String x = "{Hi This Is My String}, I Want To Add New Line Here";
System.out.println(x.replaceAll(regex,"$1\n"));
```

Output

```
{Hi This Is My String},
I Want To Add New Line Here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String x = "{Hi This Is My String},$ I Want To Add New Line Here";
        x = x.replace("$","\n");
```